# How to do actions on members of child class templates from an abstact base class?

Tags: c++, oop, templates, multiple-inheritance

I know this question gets asked a lot, but I have a specific use case, so I don't think it's a duplicate!

I have an abstract base class:

```cpp
template<int N>
class Child;

class Base
{

public:
     // Factory-like generation of children as Base
     static Ptr<Base> New(int baseN)
     {
         if (baseN == 2) return new Child<2>(); 
         else if (baseN == 3) return new Child<3>()
     }

     // Update
     virtual void update() = 0;
};
```

And I'm writing some children of `Base` as class templates (on an int):

```cpp
template<int N>
class Child
:
    public Base
{
     // Member, N is not the size of matrix, more like the size of a component in matrix
     Matrix<N> m_member;

public:
     // Implement update
     virtual void update();

     // Should call the passed callable on m_member
     virtual void execute(std::function<void(Matrix<N>&)>&);
};

// Force compilation of Child<N>  for some values of N (of interest, including 3) here

// Then,
int baseN = 3;
Ptr<Base> obj = Base::New(baseN); // will get me a Child<3> as a Base object


auto callable = [](Matrix<3>) ->void {};

// Can I access Child<3>::m_member ??
// Can't cast to Child<baseN> (baseN is not constexpr) and don't want to
// But want to do something like:
obj->execute(callable);
// Which forwards 'callable' to the method from concrete type, probably using a cast?
```

In short, I need to have some sort of access to `m_member` from the declared `Base` object.
Preferably, a way to call `Child<N>::execute` from `Base` without making Base a template on N too.

Things I've tried/thought-of include:

1. 'Type erasure' of `Matrix<N>` by hiding them behind an interface, but because `Matrix<N>`'s interface strongly depends on N, doing that renders the classes useless (think: `Vector<N>& Matrix<N>::diag()` for example)
2. Can `Base::New` do anything to record what concrete type it creates? I doubt that because types are not objects.

**EDIT:** (Btw this is C++11)

So, I accidentally figured out a way to do this; but I don't **quite understand why** the following works (Not well versed into assembly yet):

- I'm using a Database for objects (`unordered_map<string, object*>` where `object` is a class that every registered object has to inherit from).
- When a Child is created, we register it to a database with a name of `Child<N>`.
- Then, at application-level code, there is a `findChild<int N>` template which employs compile-time recursion to find which concrete class was the Base pointer created from (At runTime, by dynamicCasting and testing). When It finds it, it can cast it to `void*` through a static method (`findChild<N>::castToConcrete`)
- What's interesting is that we can somehow use `findChild<0>` to access the `findChild<N>` in question if `Child<N>` is polymorphic. This forces us to have at most one object of Child (for all possible Ns) and I certainly can live with that.

You can see and inspect a minimal code example here: https://onlinegdb.com/CiGR1Fq5z

What I'm so confused about is that `Child<0>` and other `Child<N>` are completely different types; So how can we access one's members from a pointer to another type? I'm most likely relying on UB and even fear there is a stack smacking of some sort!

For reference, I'm including the code here in case the link dies.

```cpp
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#ifndef MAX_N_VALUE
    #define MAX_N_VALUE 10
#endif // !MAX_N_VALUE

// ------------------ Lib code

// A dummy number class for testing only
template <int N> struct Number { constexpr static int value = N; };

// Objects to register to the database
struct object
{
    // Members
    string name;

    // construction/Destruction
    object(const string& name) : name(name) {}
    virtual ~object(){};
};


// Database of objects
struct DB
: public unordered_map<string, object*>
{
    // See if we can the object of name "name" and type "T" in the DB
    template <class T>
    bool found(const string& name) const
    {
        unordered_map<string,object*>::const_iterator iter = find(name);
        if (iter != end())
        {
            const T* ptr = dynamic_cast<const T*>(iter->second);
            if (ptr) return true;
            cout << name << " found but it's of another type." << endl;
            return false;
        }
        cout << name << " not found." << endl;
        return false;
    }

    // Return a const ref to the object of name "name" and type "T" in the DB
    // if found. Else, fails
    template <class T>
    const T& getObjectRef(const string& name) const
    {
        unordered_map<string,object*>::const_iterator iter = find(name);
        if (iter != end())
        {
            const T* ptr = dynamic_cast<const T*>(iter->second);
            if (ptr) return *ptr;
            cout << name << " found but it's of another type." << endl;
            abort();
        }
        cout << name << " not found." << endl;
        abort();
    }
};


// Forward declare children templates
template<int N>
class Child;

// The interface class
struct Base
{
    // Construction/Destruction
protected:
    static unsigned counter;
    Base(){}
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}

    // Factory-like generation of children as Base
    // THIS New method needs to know how to construct Child<N>
    // so defining it after Child<N>
    static Base* New(int baseN, DB& db);

    // Update
    virtual void update() = 0;
    
    // Call a callable on a child, the callable interface
    // however is independent on N
    virtual void execute(std::function<void(Base&)>& callable)
    {
        callable(*this);
    }
};

unsigned Base::counter = 0;

// The concrete types, which we register to the DB
template<int N>
struct Child
:
    public Base, public object
{
    // members
    vector<Number<N>> member;

    // Construction/Destruction 
    Child() : Base(), object(string("Child") + to_string(N) + ">"), member(N, Number<N>()) {}
    virtual ~Child() {}

    // Test member method (Has to be virtual)
    virtual vector<Number<N>> test() const
    {
        cout << "Calling Child<" << N << ">::test()" << endl;
        return vector<Number<N>>(N, Number<N>());
    }

    // Implement update
    virtual void update()
    {
        cout << "Calling Child<" << N << ">::update()" << endl;
    };
};

// New Base, This can be much more sophisticated
// if static members are leveraged to register constructors
// and invoke them on demand.
Base* Base::New(int baseN, DB& db)
{
    if (baseN == 2)
    {
        Child<2>* c = new Child<2>();
        db.insert({string("Child<")+std::to_string(2)+">", c});
        return c;
    }
    if (baseN == 3)
    {
        Child<3>* c = new Child<3>();
        db.insert({string("Child<")+std::to_string(3)+">", c});
        return c;
    }
    return nullptr;
}

// Finder template for registered children
template<int N>
struct findChild
{
    // Concrete Type we're matching against
    using type = Child<N>;

    // Stop the recursion?
    static bool stop;

    // Compile-time recursion until the correct Child is caught
    // Recursion goes UP in N values
    static void* castToConcrete(const DB& db, Base* system)
    {
        if (N > MAX_N_VALUE) stop = true;
        if (stop) return nullptr;
        if (db.found<type>(string("Child<")+to_string(N)+">"))
        {
            type* ptr = dynamic_cast<type*>(system);
            return static_cast<void*>(ptr);
        }
        // NOTE: This should jump to the next "compiled" child, not just N+1, but meh;
        return findChild<N+1>::castToConcrete(db, system);
    }
};

// Activate recursive behaviour for arbitraty N
template<int N>
bool findChild<N>::stop = false;

// Explicit specialization to stop the Compile-time recursion at a decent child
template<>
struct findChild<MAX_N_VALUE+1>
{
    using type = Child<MAX_N_VALUE+1>;
    static bool stop;
    static void* castToConcrete(const DB& t, const Base* system)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
};

// Disactivate recursive behaviour for N = 11
bool findChild<MAX_N_VALUE+1>::stop = true;


// ------------------ App code

int main()
{
    // Create objects database
    DB db;

    // --- Part 1: Application writers can't write generic-enough code

    // Select (from compiled children) a new Base object with N = 2
    // and register it to the DB
    Base* b = Base::New(2, db);
    b->update();

    cout << "Access children by explicit dynamic_cast to Child<N>:" << endl;

    // Get to the object through the objects DB.
    // Child destructor should remove the object from DB too, nut meh again
    const auto& oo = db.getObjectRef<Child<2>>("Child<2>");
    cout << oo.test().size() << endl;

    // --- Part 2: Application writers can write generic code if the compile
    // Child<N> for their N

    cout << "If Child<N> is polymorphic, we can access the correct child from findChild<0>:" << endl;

    // Create a lambda that knows about db, which Base applies on itself
    function<void(Base&)> lambda = [&db](Base& base) -> void {
        // Cast and ignore the result
        void* ptr = findChild<0>::castToConcrete(db, &base);

        // Cast back to Child<0>
        findChild<0>::type* c = static_cast<findChild<0>::type*>(ptr);

        // Now access original Child<N> methods and members from Child<0>
        cout << "Method:\n" << c->test().size() << endl;
        cout << "Member:\n" << c->member.size() << endl;
    };

    b->execute(lambda);

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled with GCC 9 with the following options:

```
-m64 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wold-style-cast -Wnon-virtual-dtor -O0 -fdefault-inline -ftemplate-depth-200
```

Comment: afaict you can't even reach `execute`?

Comment: Yes, because of the dependence of the argument to the callable on "Matrix<N>"

Comment: The question would be much clearer if you would post a [mcve] together with the error message. For example what is `Ptr` ? Also I suggest tackle one problem at a time. I don't see how you want to create a `Child<3>` via calling `Base::New(baseN);` and then I am already lost

Comment: Ptr is just a placeholder for a smart pointer class, I can't build an MRE because the new() function depends on a ton of other things, + i'm not even at the stage of getting errors :)

Comment: if those ton of other things are relevent for the quesiton then you should include them. If they are not, why can you not replace it with a switch? or `if (baseN == 1) return new Child<1>(); else if (baseN == 2) return new Child<2>();` ?

Comment: "already now how to do that, and it works" does not help us to reproduce your current issue

Comment: New method checks a hash table of registered children (registered through their constrctors, the table is a static member) and calls the appropriate constructor to create the appropriate type

Comment: does it do something similar to `if (baseN == 1) return new Child<1>(); else if (baseN == 2) return new Child<2>()` ? If yes you can use that instead of the hash table

Comment: Ah yes, the if statements are good, thanks

Comment: You want to call execute which requires a function that takes `Matrix<N>`, but where do you plan to get that function?

Comment: That's the callable lambda expression, the client code can specify it

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's lambda or any other kind of callable. So some client code supplies that callable. How does *that code* know what N is?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Can you guys take a second look? There is an interesting update on this :)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Can you guys take a second look? Call in anyone who can clarify this please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want inheritance to group not so related classes...

[`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) (C++17) might be more appropriate:

```
template<int N>
class Child
{
     // Member, N is not the size of matrix, more like the size of a component in matrix
     Matrix<N> m_member;

public:
     void update();

     void execute(std::function<void(Matrix<N>&)> f) { f(m_member); }
};

using Base = std::variant<Child<2>, Child<3>>;
```

and then:

```
void foo(Base& obj)
{
    struct Visitor {
        template <std::size_t N>
        void operator()(Child<N>& c) const
        {
            auto callable = [](Matrix<N>) -> void {/*..*/};
            c.execute(callable);
        }
    } visitor;
    std::visit(visitor, obj);
}
```

To answer to your Edit, whereas your callable take a `Base`, you might chain the `dynamic_cast` as follow:

```
template <int N>
void foo_base(Base& b)
{
    if (auto* child = dynamic_cast<Child<N>*>(&b)) {
        // Job with Child<N>
        std::cout << "Method:" << child->test().size() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Member:" << child->member.size() << std::endl;
    }
}

template <int... Ns>
void foo_dispatch(std::integer_sequence<int, Ns...>, Base& base)
{
    //(foo_base<Ns>(base), ...); // C++17
    const int dummy[] = {0, (foo_base<Ns>(base), 0)...};
    static_cast<void>(dummy); // Avoid warning about unused variable
}
```

With a call similar to:

```
function<void(Base&)> lambda = [](Base& base) {
    //foo_dispatch(std::integer_sequence<int, 2, 3>(), base);
    foo_dispatch(std::make_integer_sequence<int, MAX_N_VALUE>(), base);
};
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/M5lqqj_To)

([`std::integer_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) is C++14, but can be implemented in C++11)

Comment: Yeah, this looks like a feasible solution, but will make me lose runtime selection of child objects. If nothing else comes out, I'll consider this as an excepted answer

Comment: You can still have `Base MakeBase(int baseN) { if (baseN == 2) return {Child<2>()}; else return {Child<3>()}; }`.

Comment: What `Variants` parameter pack can be deduced from this call to `visit`? Your visitor should somehow know about *all existing instantiations* of `Child`, but where does it get the complete list?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: OP's factory is also limited, so I expect than number of valid type is also limited (my `using Base = std::variant<Child<2>, Child<3>>;` can be extended, but indeed, all possible type should be known at compile time).

Comment: Yes, it's somewhat limited, N is in range 2..10 typically, my current code lets clients add other `Child<N>` in separate (dynamically loaded) libraries  (by forcing the compiler to compile the desired Child object) and protects against undefined references, but I'm willing to trade this for making execute to work. Although i would really like to keep Base a class

Comment: 3 days and no activity; I'm accepting this answer as I think it's the best we could do!
Still suffers from the fact is that if a client wants to add a new `Child<n>`, they have to recompile my library. But oh, well, that can't be remedied. I'll just have to instantiate enough `Child<n>`s.

Comment: @Jarod42 There is an update on this, can you take a look please?

Comment: You have indeed UB ([Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/n8thiX2W4) with "invalid" output) as you cast `Child<2>*` as `Child<0>*` (and your `Db` overcomplicate stuff, whereas you just want to chain the `dynamic_cast`).

Comment: Whereas `std::variant` is C++17, there is the boost one (or from other lib) for C++11.

Comment: Oh man, I don't know how I missed checking the values!!!
Thanks! If I use `template <int N> struct Number { constexpr static int value = N; int runValue = N; };`
`value` as a static variable will always say 0 (somehow this points to Child<0>::value); but `runValue` will say 2 for `Child<2>`.
I now think the missing piece is the ability to store the concrete type and cast back to it.
Your solution is definitely safer.

Answer (score 0):

> Note: Jarod's answer is still a little bit better if you know possible
> values of N in `Child<N>` at compile-time and don't want to provide a way to extend them. Plus, of course, if you can use C++17.

Here I'm relying on "Similar types" defined by the standard as:

> **4.4 Qualification conversions [conv.equal]**
>
> ... trimmed ...
>
> Two pointer types T1 and T2 are similar if there exists a type T and integer n > 0 such that:
>
> T1 is cv(1,0) pointer to cv(1,1) pointer to ··· cv(1,n−1) pointer to cv(1,n) T
>
> and
>
> T2 is cv(2,0) pointer to cv(2,1) pointer to ··· cv(2,n−1) pointer to (cv2,n) T
>
> where each cv(i,j) is `const`, `volatile`, `const volatile`, or nothing

The same paragraph also shows the conditions for converting expressions.
In short, By inheriting from `Base`, all `Child<N>*` pointer types are similar to `Base*`, hence similar to each other.

Now, we know we can `static_cast` `Child<N>` to `Child<0>` without problems.
But is accessing `Child<3>` members from a `Child<0>*` safe?

> **3.10 Lvalues and rvalues [basic.lval]**
>
> 10. If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the
>     following types the behavior is undefined:
>
> - the dynamic type of the object,
> - ... trimmed ...
> - a type similar (as defined in 4.4) to the dynamic type of the object

There you have it, Accessing the values of `Child<3>` though a `Child<0>*` is in fact defined behavior.

This piece of code:

```cpp
    Base* b = Base::New(2);
    b->update();
    
    Child<2>* c1 = static_cast<Child<2>*>(b);
    c1->update();
    cout << c1->t.sValue << " " << c1->t.rValue << endl;
    
    Child<0>* c2 = static_cast<Child<0>*>(b);
    c2->update();
    cout << c2->t.sValue << " " << c2->t.rValue << endl;
```

Will actually output (Note the value of the static variable `Test<N>::sValue`):

```
Calling Child<2>::update()
Calling Child<2>::update()
2 2
Calling Child<2>::update()
0 2
```

Static members will always point to `Child<0>`, and because of that,
Jarod's answer is a better solution for this problem.

But if one wants to allow expanding possible N values, this solution is OK; you just have to remember to put your static variables in `Base` and not in `Child<N>`.

Here is a minimal example, showing how to pass a lambda to the `Base*` while in fact the lambda, casts the pointer to `Child<0>` and operates on it:

https://onlinegdb.com/TTcMqOmWi